# Getting the document field names and adding them as nested fields in an Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Im writing a mongodb aggregate pipeline.
My documents are of the form below :

```
   {
  name: "01"
  tags {
  tag_01: {
    a: "a01-val",
    b: "b01-val"
  },
  tag_02: {
    a: "a02-val",
    b: "b02-val"
  }
  }
},
{
  name: "02"
  tags {
  tag_03: {
    a: "a03-val",
    b: "b03-val"
  },
  tag_04: {
    a: "a04-val",
    b: "b04-val"
  }
  }
}
```

My pipeline should generate documents as below :

```
{
  name: "01"
  tags {
  tag_01: {
    a: "a01-val",
    b: "b01-val",
    tagName: "tag_01"
  },
  tag_02: {
    a: "a02-val",
    b: "b02-val",
    tagName: "tag_02"
  }
  }
},
{
  name: "02"
  tags {
  tag_03: {
    a: "a03-val",
    b: "b03-val",
    tagName: "tag_03"
  },
  tag_04: {
    a: "a04-val",
    b: "b04-val",
    tagName: "tag_04"
  }
  }
}
```

In other words, a new field is added inside each subdocument whose value is the name of the parent field.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$objectToArray` to convert `tags` into an array of k-v tuples. Use `$map` to iterate through the array elements and `$mergeObjects` to set the field with `k`. Then use `$arrayToObject` to revert back to original object form.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "tags": {
        "$objectToArray": "$tags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "tags": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$tags",
          "as": "tag",
          "in": {
            k: "$$tag.k",
            v: {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$tag.v",
                {
                  "tagName": "$$tag.k"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tags: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$tags"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/moHIijmX_m1)

Comment: I had almost given up after spending many hours. This was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

- Start with `$objectToArray` on `tags`, then unwind it to get one record/document per tag / k-v tuples.
- Set the `tagName` field in each of those `v` objects, using the value of `k` in each of the unwound tags.
- Group them back together using `$push` to get an array of the previously unwound `k-v` objects.

  - If you have other fields, use `fieldName: { $first: "$fieldName" }` to add them or use `$mergeObjects` with `$$ROOT`, depending on how many of them/ease of writing.
- And then use `$arrayToObject` to get tags in the original form.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      tags: { $objectToArray: "$tags" }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$tags" },
  {
    $set: {
      tags: { v: { tagName: "$tags.k" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      tags: { $push: "$tags" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tags: { $arrayToObject: "$tags" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kd-D6ZclDBL)

PS. For performance, you're probably better off with [ray's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77649983/1431750).